# Match only parenthesis with closing

Tags: regex

I made a a regexp to match telephone numbers like these:

```
555-555-5555
(555)555-5555
(555) 555-5555
555 555 5555
5555555555
1 555 555 5555
```

It works. But I don't want to match numbers with no closing parenthesis like this:

```
555) 555-5555
```

This is my regexp:

```
^(1{1})?(\ |-)?(\()?([0-9]{3})(\ |\)|\-)?(\ |\)|\-)?([0-9]{3})(\ |-)?([0-9]{4})$
```

How can I do it?

Comment: This will help you massively http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html

Comment: `{1}` is redundant.

Comment: What programming language or text editor are you using?

Comment: Do you *really* need to capture all the parts in separate groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must cater for both brackets *or* no brackets:

```
(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})
```

all together:

```
^1?[ -]?(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})[ -]?\d{3}[ -]?\d{4}$
```

...with unnecessary brackets removed and simpler character classes added.

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/PPLaVvgwuc).

Answer (score 0):

On which type of content your regex will be applied?

Because you may have different solutions.

If you are on a field that contain only the phone number, and want to validate them, you may start by strip all chars except digits, and have a nice value to work on.

Answer (score 0):

Just to put my two cents in:

```
(?:(?=\(\d+\))|(?!.*\)))
^[\d- ()]+$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/Uoe6hG/1).
Or, simply replace `(` and `)` with nothing prior to matching.